# Proof such recursive set existence.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-complexity, computability, recursive-algorithms

Recently my teacher gave me the following task to think about, while I've failed to solve it properly and already lost my opportunity to increase term mark, I am still have no ideas of how to really solve it. Unfortunately my teacher has no enough time to explain me this task properly. Maybe someone here has any ideas?

X, Y - recursive sets, such as

$X / Y=\{t\in \mathbb{N}| \exists x\in X, \exists y\in Y: x=yt\} is non-recursive$
Whether following recursive sets X and Y may exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathbb N=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$, the set of all natural numbers; let $p_n$ denote the $n^\text{th}$ prime number.

Let $W$ be a recursively enumerable set which is not recursive.

Let $f:\mathbb N\to W$ be a recursive surjection.

$X=\{p_{f(n)}^n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is a recursive set.

$Y=\mathbb N$ is a recursive set.

The set $X/Y=X/\mathbb N$ is not recursive, because for $n\in\mathbb N$ we have
$$n\in W\iff p_n\in X/Y.$$

Comment: And why does such $f$ does exist? And what's meant here under $p_{f(n)}^{n}$?

Comment: Such an $f$ exists by the definition of a recursively enumerable set. A nonempty recursively enumerable set is the range of a recursive function. I defined $p_n$ as the $n^\text{th}$ prime number, so $p_{f(n)}$ is the $f(n)^\text{th}$ prime number, and $p_{f(n)}^n$ is the $f(n)^\text{th}$ prime number raised to the $n^\text{th}$ power. For example, if $f(3)=4$, then $p_{f(3)}^3=p_4^3=7^3=7\times7\times7=343$, because the fourth prime number is $7$.